# Google chrome 'chrome://view-http-cache' vs 'chrome://cache/'

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

The network traffic monitoring is driving me crazy. All I want to be able to track all the requests from different chrome extensions. For this I tried various approaches:

1. webRequest API: This captures only the content script requests
2. devtool API: This works only if devtool is opened and selenium and devtool can not work at a time(https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/help/devtools-window-keeps-closing), so can not use this approach as well.
3. Selenium 2 with proxy: This works well but I don't want to use third party library for this small task
4. Then I have 'chrome://view-http-cache/' and 'chrome://cache/': I googled around this to get good understanding of it. I want to know how google chrome populate these and what stuff they have with this. Where I can read more about these two services ? What is the difference between these two ?

Comment: Based on this [site](http://www.stugon.com/complete-list-of-allchrome-urls-purposes/), `chrome://cache` is used to see all the cached items like website, images, data, etc. while `chrome://view-http-cache` displays all the website that you have visited.